# bind grid view with selected date list with selected days

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

i want to bind grid look like this or sql query through bind

look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '2014-06-02'
SET @endDate = '2014-06-26'
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date,DATENAME(Dw,@startdate) As DayName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date]),DATENAME(Dw,DATEADD(d,1,[Date])) as DayName
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)

SELECT Date,DayName frOM dates where DAYNAME in('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday')
```